# Is it possible to switch git repository branch from different folder?

Tags: git, git-pull

Is there any way to switch the branch of some git repository from different directory?

Same like `git pull`

So to pull a repository from different directory I have the version of pull like this

```
git -C c:\MyDirectory\MyRepository pull
```

Is there any similar version for `git switch` as well?

Comment: Note that global Git options (such as `git -C <dir>`) work for *all* Git commands, as a rule. (That's why they appear before the specific command.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. You use global option [`-C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt) just like with git-pull.

```
git -C c:\MyDirectory\MyRepository switch branch-name
```